# Different network behavior in Rust vs Java when sending packets as fast as possible

Tags: java, networking, rust

I'm running some networking experiments to measure how fast Rust can send TCP packets over the network.

To do this, I generate a vector of 100 random packets with custom size and then loop over that array, sending a packet and reading it back.

For a few thousand packets this works fine, however the program blocks if the number of packets to send is 50k or more.

Initially, I thought this might be some throttling from the kernel/TCP stack and I've written an equivalent (I think) Java program. Surprisingly, Java works fine (it finishes regardless of the target number of packets) but Rust gets stuck.

I've observed this in macOS 10.14.2 with Java 9.0.4 and Linux with OpenJDK 9.

- Are these programs equivalent? If not, what's the fundamental difference?
- If they are equivalent, what explains the Rust behavior?

#### Rust

```rust
extern crate argparse;
extern crate rand;

use std::io::{Error, Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Instant;

use argparse::{ArgumentParser, Store, StoreTrue};
use rand::Rng;

fn start_server(port: u16) {
    let addr = format!("{}:{}", "0.0.0.0", port);
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(addr).expect("Could not bind");
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Err(e) => eprintln!("failed: {}", e),
            Ok(stream) => {
                handle_client(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) -> Result<(), Error> {
    println!("Incoming connection from: {}", stream.peer_addr()?);
    let mut buf = [0; 512];
    loop {
        let bytes_read = stream.read(&mut buf)?;
        if bytes_read == 0 {
            return Ok(());
        }
        stream.write(&buf[..bytes_read])?;
    }
}

fn start_client(port: u16, packets_to_send: u32, packet_size: u32) {
    let addr = format!("{}:{}", "127.0.0.1", port);
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(addr).expect("Could not connect to server");

    let nb_packets = 100;
    let start = Instant::now();
    let random_packets = gen_random_packets(nb_packets, packet_size);
    let stop = Instant::now().duration_since(start);
    println!("Packets generated, took {:?}", stop);

    let mut packets_sent = 1;
    let start = Instant::now();
    loop {
        let mut buffer = [0 as u8; 32];

        let index = packets_to_send % nb_packets as u32;
        //println!("sent: {} missing: {} mod:{}", packets_sent, packets_to_send, index);

        let to_send = &random_packets[index as usize];
        stream.write(to_send).expect("Failed to write to server");

        stream
            .read(&mut buffer)
            .expect("Failed to read from server.");

        packets_sent += 1;

        if packets_sent > packets_to_send {
            break;
        }

        if (packets_sent % 1000) == 0 {
            println!("Packets sent {} / total {}", packets_sent, packets_to_send);
        }
    }

    let stop = Instant::now().duration_since(start);

    println!("Wrote {} packets in {:?}", packets_sent, stop)
}

fn gen_random_packets(nb: u16, size: u32) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut random_bytes = Vec::with_capacity(nb as usize);

    for _ in 0..nb {
        random_bytes.push((0..size).map(|_| rand::random::<u8>()).collect());
    }

    random_bytes
}

fn main() {
    // default configuration
    let mut port = 8888;
    let mut server = false;
    let mut packets_to_send = 100;
    let mut packet_size = 256;
    //read config parameters from stdin, if any
    {
        let mut ap = ArgumentParser::new();
        ap.set_description("Rust network.");
        ap.refer(&mut server).add_option(
            &["--server"],
            StoreTrue,
            "Whether to spawn a server or a client, defaults to client.",
        );
        ap.refer(&mut port)
            .add_option(&["--port"], Store, "Listening port");
        ap.refer(&mut packets_to_send).add_option(
            &["--packets"],
            Store,
            "Number of packets to send",
        );
        ap.refer(&mut packet_size)
            .add_option(&["--packet-size"], Store, "Packet size");
        ap.parse_args_or_exit();
    }

    if server {
        start_server(port);
    } else {
        println!(
            "Starting client, connecting to port {}. Sending {} packets.",
            port, packets_to_send
        );
        start_client(port, packets_to_send, packet_size);
    }
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/miguelammatos/6ca284132908b53d773af944d1ca3f9c)

#### Java

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Network {


    public static  void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
        int port = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        boolean server =Boolean.valueOf(args[1]);
        int packets_to_send = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);


        if(server){
        start_server(port);
        } else  {

            start_client(port,packets_to_send);

        }
    }

    private static void start_server(int port) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Starting server");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Listening");
            Socket sock = ss.accept();

            try{

            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();


            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            while (true) {
                is.read(buffer);
                os.write(buffer);
            }
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception e"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void start_client(int port, int packets_to_send) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Starting client");
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",port);

        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();

        Random rand = new Random();
        byte[][] packets = new byte[100][256];

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < packets.length; i++) {
            rand.nextBytes(packets[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Packets generated: %d", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));

        int packets_sent=1;

        byte[] buff = new byte[256];


        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(packets_sent < packets_to_send) {

            os.write(packets[ packets_to_send % packets.length]);

            is.read(buff);
            packets_sent++;
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Packets sent: %d Time: %d", packets_sent, System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        System.out.println("Done!");

    }
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/miguelammatos/9d72be4a6b7ac793de86b0f386e131f0)

Comment: It doesn't look like it's spawning a thread per request. It looks like it's a thread per client.

Comment: I would run Linux `strace` on both programs and see if the "look" the same from the system call level.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Yes, you're right. Still - it doesn't seem equivalent, because the Java version doesn't spawn anything at all, or does it? Also, the java version doesn't do anything with the number of bytes read, and it doesn't use `readFully` (or whatever it's called).

Comment: It doesn't. The Java version is limited to one client at at time.

Comment: Could you please **[edit]** your question to address why *you* think that these two pieces of code are the same? As the previous comments point out, one implementation spawns threads and the other does not. That's a pretty drastic difference in architecture.

Comment: Your `handle_client` can [be simplified and optimized](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ae710df7b63bc43d0e8e120861d58b4).

Comment: Why are you reading into a 32-byte long buffer in the Rust code?

Comment: `let index = packets_to_send % nb_packets as u32;`, this value never change also this cast is ugly. I don't think we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Yes, the java program is single threaded but I was using this only with one client at at time. I've updated the rust program to be single-threaded too. The problem was in the receiver's buffer size. See answer below.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the pointer. It's indeed simpler but I don't understand how it's more 'optimal'. Looking at the implemetantion of io::copy (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/io/util.rs) it creates an additional buffer in memory each time it is invoked while this just reuses the buffer. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user10998402 your `handle_client` also creates the `buf` every time it is called, so I don't understand your point. Neither of them matter because they are both stack-allocated. `io::copy` is more efficient because it has a bigger buffer, doesn't zero out the buffer, and more correct because it handles more error cases.

Comment: Don’t understand the downvotes. The author asked a clear, answerable question, and supplied the actual code that was failing.

Comment: @Shepmaster handle_client creates the buffer once per client client while io::copy creates it multiple times per client (once per sucesful read). I agree with the rest of your points though.

Comment: @user10998402 both implementations create one buffer once per client. I do not understand how you see anything else.

Comment: @WillisBlackburn one possibility is that there are obvious differences between the two pieces of code (the threading and the fixed sized buffers are ones that have been mentioned in the comments). The OP asked if there were any differences in the two pieces of code hey wrote, but didn’t **seemingly** take any time of their own to compare the two. Who knows why people downvote though.

Comment: I agree the OP missed something, but almost every OP is missing something, that’s why they’re asking for help. Last week I pointed out that someone’s problem was due to there being an unwanted semicolon after a while statement. We’ve all been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write 256 octet:

```
let mut packet_size = 256;
```

but you only read 32 in your client:

```
let mut buffer = [0 as u8; 32];
```

So the write buffer in the server is full cause the client don't read all the available data, so the server will block on its write call waiting that the client read the packet, and the client will also block on the write call because the server has stop reading the socket.

You can fix this with a bigger size for your read buffer:

```
let mut buffer = [0u8; 512];
```

Or better you should always read the socket when there is data available, any non trivial program must do it.

Comment: This was the issue indeed.